# BLE scaning Gap when application in background?

Tags: service, bluetooth-lowenergy, timertask

I am getting scanning gap 5-8 sec when application is in background. In that period, I am not getting BLE device is in scan  I have used service and `TimerTask` for it.

Comment: Are you using any filter for your scan? Non-filtered scans don't work in the background.

Comment: Every thing is working in foreground on every device, and it is also working fine in Pixel2 (Oreo) foreground as well as background but I am getting problem with Samsung (nougat)  only background case.